# Программирование под Android...Какие есть книги Android NDK? как его изучать?

Tags: android, c++

Можно ли использовать язык C++?
И что необходимо для написания приложения?

Comment: гугли ndk... игры писать можно

Comment: java-то чем не устроила? Она проще, во многом удобнее, литературы по ней навалом в отличие от таковой по Android-разработке на С++. А с С++ вы дерьма хлебнете, это уж наверняка

Comment: @Анатолийй, определись сначала, что действительно хочется изучать: NDK и SDK хоть и относятся к одной сфере, но в корне своем, принципиально разные технологии.

---
NDK, как правило, используется не так уж и часто при разработке. Отчасти потому, что в нем нет реального смысла, наверное, в 95% случаях. В основном он предназначен для написания низкоуровневых функций, что бы потом их вызывать из той же Java среды.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

начните с http://startandroid.ru/ru/ 
все с самого начала и подробно, у сайта есть и свой канал на YouTube.com https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzE7HcbvyEiS5ea1rVRbPLQ 
постепенно все уроки переводят в видео